# Lightweight Webservice producing in Java (without an application server)

Tags: java, web-services

Is there any Java library allowing to build a simple standalone webservice server without any application server framework?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Java 6 contains JAX-WS, which makes it very easy to host a web service in a stand-alone application:

```
javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8000/myService/", myServiceImplementation);
```

Comment: That's pretty cool, but is there a servlet equivalent, so I can run without a application server?

Comment: @GGB667: that's pretty much an entirely separate question, please ask that as a separate question (or better yet: search for it, I wouldn't be surprised if SO already had an answer for that).

Comment: I couldn't find a nice one-liner like that, but found various tools that can be combined to create one with some work, nothing that elegant.  :<

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-jse/

Comment: I've seen your answer, tried it, but gut stuck reading details of the request, could you please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/37256836/4142984 to clear my confusion or to add more info? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

[Axis 2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/) has a simple standalone server (see http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_4_1/installationguide.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Simple](http://www.simpleframework.org:Simple) is the fastest and lightest NIO web server you will find in the Java world. About twice as fast as Jetty and a quarter the size.

Answer (score 1):

[Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty/) can be run embedded in a java application. Have a look at it.